# How to include a file/subfolder from an excluded folder?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a situation where I need to include one file into the TSC build that is under a folder that contains other unneeded files. How can I generally specify to TSC in the tsconfig file that I need these specific files/subfolders from a folder, otherwise ignore it?

for example:

```
/.
 |-folder 1
     |->file2.ts 
 |->src.ts
 |-folder 2 //ignored
     |->file1.ts //This file is needed
     |->file2.ts //the rest should be ignored
     |->...
```

Because of the way we use namespaces in TS i would like to include the @types folder from node modules, but ignore everything else. currently the tsconfig.json is :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outFile": "Compile/Result.js",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "Compile/Result.d.ts",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ]
}
```

But this does not work currently

Comment: What happens when you include it this way => `"include": ["node_modules/@types", "YOUR_FILE_PATH/YOUR_FILE_NAME.EXTENSION"]` ?

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure what you mean with "YOUR_FILE_PATH/YOUR_FILE_NAME.EXTENSION" as I want to include the root dir of the project and all the subdirectories, except node modules, but including the @types folder.

Answer (score 1):

Files included using "include" can be filtered using the "exclude" property. However, files included explicitly using the "files" property are always included regardless of "exclude". 
Use

```
"files": ["yourFilePath"]
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: If I understand the doc properly, this would mean that I have to use the files property with all the files in the project. No mix and match with include? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Zooming in on your requirements:

```
/.
 |-folder 2 //ignored
     |->file1.ts //This file is needed
     |->file2.ts //the rest should be ignored
     |->...
```

Your config needs to be

```
"exclude": [
    "folder 2"
  ],
  "include": [
    "folder 2/file1.ts"
  ]
```

Comment: I think I fell to this same pitfall, as now my project includes just the folder2/file1.ts. I need to also include all the other files in the root directory and other directoreis